# Need to store information about people in a file and pull out specific information (python)

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm relatively new to python, and the program I need to make requires me to store a set of information about a person within a file that also contains the same information about other people. I think I have to use a 2d dictionary or something like that, but I'm not sure. I need to be able to:
- display the info to a person- eventually in a GUI (don't know how to make GUIs yet, but I will learn later)
- edit any of the information on a person
- add any amount of new people to this file
- use all of the information from a 'column' and turn it into its own temporary list. for example, a list that had the ages of every person. any help you can give is appreciated.
BTW I don't have code to show, I'm still in the planning stage.

Comment: can you show the how data stored in file and expected output

Comment: I think it might be better if you could make an attempt and show the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Name:\n") #Take in info
age = input("Age:\n")
hobby = input("Hobby:\n")

abc = open("test.txt", "a+") #Open the file
abc.write(name, age, hobby)

namesearch = input("Search: ") #Ask to search

with open("test.txt") as fo: #Open file
    for rec in fo: #Start a for loop to search line by line 
        tokens = rec.strip().split(',', 2) # split to maximum three tokens
        if tokens[0] == namesearch: #if token number 1(name)=namesearch then,
            print(rec) #Return the whole line
```